# distinict странно считает в mysql (mariadb10.0)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Есть база (20К строк примерно), в базе  клиенты,  в том числе  столбец **email**.  При заполнении проверялась уникальность, поле описано с индексом, но без уникальности.  Таблица описана и поле описаны как

```
`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Значения двух сторок для одного столбца логически совпадают, то есть использую перл, но для bash более читаемо.

```bsh
a=`echo 'select email from cl_data where columnd=4964;' | mysql mailwiz ` ; b=`echo 'select email from cl_data where columnd=7914;' | mysql mailwiz`; if  [ "$a" == "$b" ] ; then echo EQ; else echo  NE ; fi
```

выведет EQ.

---

Также  видим MySQL что все поля уникальны:

```
select count(distinct(lower(email)))-(count(email)) from cl_data; --  Дает 0.
```

Но сверка двух полей на уникальность  дает различия:

```
select count(distinct(lower(email))) from cl_data where email in (select email from cl_data  where columnd =7914); -- выводит 2 ( ожидаемо 1).
```

В логах ошибок как SQL, так и сервера молчание...  Куда копать и что смотреть?

Comment: Ну вроде очевидно, что у вас два разных email с идентичным columnd =7914

Comment: не вписал, сорри  `columnd` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`columnd`)
да и  count по нему  совадает (count(email))